# Conditional synchronization of multiple application requests

Tags: java, database, web-services, hibernate, spring

I have the following problem:

I have a multithreaded server-side application, where every request executes a new thread (the standard case). Based on this request, the application checks if the data needed is cached in the DB already. If yes, it fetches it and sends it back to the client. If not, a remote service is called the response is stored in the DB and then fetched to be returned to the client.

The service takes a while to calculate the data, and since the requests to my app are executed asynchronously, I fall into the trap of one request checking the DB, seeing that there is nothing there, then calling the service. Meanwhile however, another request with the same input would check the DB, and since the service takes a while, there still would be nothing there ... so it would initiate another call to the service. As a result, the data gets written to DB twice, which screws up any successing operations, relying on its uniqueness (there can't be two records with the same data)

What solution should I choose?
One idea would be to put specific UNIQUE field constraints in the DB. This way, even if the app tries to write twice, the DB will simply reject it, and the app will throw an exception. However, the service will still be executed multiple times.

Another solution that came to my mind would be to synchronize the method, which calls the web service. This way, every successive request to my app will be put on a waiting stack before the previous operation is finished. This way, if another request with the same input data comes in, while the first one is still waiting for the results from the remote service, it will sit and wait for the operation to be finished. Then, as the second request checks the DB, the data will already be there, and there will be no need to call the serivice again. This will also prevent from having multiple identical records in the DB. The problem with this is that the speed of my server application will be reduced inevitably, because EVERY request will have to wait, even the ones which normally shouldn't (the ones, for which supposedly we already have data in the DB)

Any other suggestions? I am stuck. How can I implement some sort of conditional synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just synchronize the calculation part, i.e. use double checked locking:

```
boolean dataExists = checkDB();
if( !dataExists ) {
  synchronized( someSharedObject ) {
    //another thread might have been waiting too and now has put the data into the DB
    //thus check again
    if( !checkDB() ) {
      calculateDataAndWriteToDB();
    }  
  }
}
//do whatever you want with the existing data
```

Comment: your someSharedObject should be your input from endUser input.Else it is good approch/

Answer (score 2):

Just implement this algorithm:

- get data from the DB
- if data exists, return data
- if data doesn't exist, get a lock associated with the id of the data to get // blocking call
- once you have the lock, check if data is in the DB, and if so, return the data. Else, call the service and put the data in the DB
- release the lock

This way, you wait on a lock only when the data doesn't exist in the DB yet. The first concurrent thread getting the lock is the only one calling the service, and all the other ones get the data from the DB.

This shouldn't prevent you from correctly designing the database, and using a unique primary key for the data. It will still be needed if you have a cluster of servers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use case that you described looks like typical caching use case. And in caches data usually has some key and value where key defines uniqueness . If other request updates the data it will not create new record but update existing one with the same key. If you do it this way the price you pay is just calling the service twice but it should not affect the logic. So is there a reason you create new record every time instead of updating?

And I highly advise against using any method synchronization in your use case as it automatically makes your solution not scalable over multiple boxes.

Comment: There's no point in updating when multiple threads concurrently prepare the data to be inserted and try to insert if. When the data is already in the DB (hence when you'd know you could update it) the OP doesn't want to take any action.

Comment: I agree. You could use locking and number of other optimizations. I described the simplest case.

Answer (score 0):

In your first approach with UNIQUE field constraints in the DB will not solve your problem as endUser will have to wait for remote service call to return and resources will be used unnecessary.

Another approach is to cancel a request with same input data and tell endUser to refresh request after some time period.But that is not good as it will enhance your server down time.

So you left with your second approach.I just suggest you to synchronize on your input data.
Or You can have some check that if input data is same then wait until request is returned and then read output from db.